# Stock price history SQL database with Python, Pandas and yfinance

Tags: python, pandas

I have a program that lists and downloads a year of history of two stock tickers (AMZN and GOOG). I download these to a SQL database, `C:\Databases\hist_prices.db`, inside a table called `hist_prices_tickers`.

How can I organize my code for a more Pythonic approach?

I intend to use this SQL database for a machine learning project later on. Is this method of calling the database the best way possible?

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3, shutil, glob, os
from pathlib import Path

NewFolderPath  = r"C:\Databases\\"
isFile = os.path.exists(NewFolderPath)
if isFile is False:
    Path(NewFolderPath).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

df = pd.DataFrame()
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
tickers = ["AMZN","GOOG"]

#SQL Connect
conn = sqlite3.connect(NewFolderPath+'hist_prices.db')
c = conn.cursor()
dest = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
conn.backup(dest)
conn.commit()

for ticker in tickers:
    tkr = yf.Ticker(ticker)
    hist = tkr.history(period="1y")
    df2 = df2.append(hist)
    df2['Ticker'] = ticker
    df = df.append(df2.reset_index())

    df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
    df = df.applymap(str)
    df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace('.', ','))
    df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(pd.to_datetime)
    df.to_sql('hist_prices_tickers', conn, index=False, if_exists='append')

df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * from hist_prices_tickers", conn)
df.drop_duplicates(subset=None, keep="last", inplace=True)
df.to_sql('hist_prices_tickers', conn,  if_exists='replace', index=False)

print(df)

conn.close()
```